# Jackson: nested object map implementation

Tags: java, jackson

Is there any way to tell [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library which Map implementation to use in nested object?

I have some Map extended from HashMap, I don't care of fields order:

```
public class FieldsMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

  @Override
  public V get(Object field) {
    V value = super.get(field);
    if (value == null && !containsKey(field)) {
        log.warn("Query unknown field " + field);
    }

    return value;
  }

}
```

And `ObjectMapper.readValue()` returns this class:

```
final TypeReference<FieldsMap<String, Object>> mapType =
    new TypeReference<FieldsMap<String, Object>>() {};

Map<String, Object> res = new ObjectMapper().readValue("{\"a\": {\"b\": 0}}", mapType);
res.get("c"); // warning
```

But the *nested* object is always `LinkedHashMap`:

```
System.out.println(res.get("a").getClass().getName()); // java.util.LinkedHashMap
((Map)res.get("a")).get("c"); // no warning
```

It will be helpful in test environments.

Comment: your json is nested json, and always nested json is with key value pair and treated as `Map`

Comment: I mean subobjects in json tree, element "a" in my example. Need a comon solution where you dont know tree structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a an **abstract type mapping** to your ObjectMapper. This is done with a module:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class FieldsMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

    @Override
    public V get(Object field) {
        V value = super.get(field);
        if (value == null && !containsKey(field)) {
            System.out.println("Query unknown field " + field);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        final TypeReference<FieldsMap<String, Object>> mapType = new TypeReference<FieldsMap<String, Object>>() {};
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule().addAbstractTypeMapping(Map.class, FieldsMap.class);
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);
        Map<String, Object> res = objectMapper.readValue("{\"a\": {\"b\": 0}}", mapType);
        res.get("c");
        System.out.println(res.get("a").getClass().getName());
        ((Map)res.get("a")).get("c");
    }
}
```

This will instruct Jackson to use your custom type `FieldsMap` each time a `Map` is needed.

The output is:

```
Query unknown field c
FieldsMap
Query unknown field c
```

Comment: @lunicon It's weird, because it does work for me. I reproduced the exact same sample you provided.  What version of Jackson do you use ?

Comment: dependencies 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.2'. Maybe I'm using it in wrong way. Can you provide full example

Comment: @lunicon I updated my answer with a full working example.

Comment: I  thought that the error was in inner class usage. No, this feature added in later version.. Thanks by the way